# Weibull Distribution Returns NULL value in R

Tags: r, statistics, null, distribution, weibull

I'm trying to calculate the shape and scale based on mean and standard deviation of a weibull distribution. If mean = 0 and sd = 1, the shape and scale both return NA. But for other values(such as mean = 1 and sd = 2), the result is perfect. Any requirement for the input parameters? I' m a beginner of statistic and R. Can someone help me out or give me any hint or reference? Thanks you so much.

```
mu = 0
sd = 1
sp = mixdist::weibullpar(mu, sd, loc = 0)$shape
sc = mixdist::weibullpar(mu, sd, loc = 0)$scale
```

Comment: What do you know about the Weibull distribution? In particular does it make any sense for a distribution that can only take values greater than 0 to have a mean of 0?

Comment: The support for Weibull distribution is 0 to positive infinite. It is impossible to have mean 0 and sd 1

Comment: Hello Dason, thank you for the comment. I'm doing a simulation by creating a set of weibull distribution data based on mean and sd. So do you mean there is no practical significance passing mean = 0?

Comment: Thank you peter861222, can you provide me some reference please?

Comment: @Timon Not only is there no practical significance - it's just impossible.

Comment: @Dason Thank you so much. That makes perfectly sense.

Answer (score 1):

For closure, the reason why a mean of 0 is inappropriate is that the [Weibull distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution) is defined on [0,  ∞). Unless the distribution always returns 0—and is thus no longer a Weibull—the mean **must** be greater than 0.